# Type List takes type parameters

Tags: scala, scopt

I have the following data:

```
val param1 = List(("f1","f2","f3"),
                  ("d1","d2","d2"))
```

The number of rows in this `List` is not fixed.

I want to pass these data as the input parameter of my Scala object.

```
import scopt.OptionParser

object Test {

  case class Params( param1: List[(String, String, String)] = null )

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val defaultParams = Params()

    val parser = new OptionParser[Params]("Test") {
      head("bla-bla")

      opt[List[(String, String, String)]]("param1")
        .required()
        .text("xxx")
        .action((x, c) => c.copy(param1 = x))
    }

    parser.parse(args, defaultParams).map { params =>
      val processor = new TestProcessor()
      processor.run(params)
    } getOrElse {
      System.exit(1)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do it? Currently, I define `String`, but it's not correct. If I use `List(String,String,String)`, then it says `Type List takes type parameters`.

Comment: Will it always be 3 String elements per row? How does `rows: List[(String, String, String)]` work?

Comment: @Tanjin: Yes, there are always 3 elements per row.

Comment: @Tanjin: I tested your proposal, but it does not fully work. I get a compilation error for `defaultParams`: `expected Test.Params, actual: (Any,Any,Any,Any)`. And for `args`: `expected Seq[String], actual: mutable.WrappedArray[String]`.

Comment: Could you please extend your code with non-working approach advised by @Tanjin and how you pass parameters to your code? (example I mean, to reproduce problem)

Comment: @Evgeny: Please see my update. The code is reproducible.

Comment: It seems like you need to define an implicit val for reading params, here is just an example to get you started: `implicit val paramsRead: scopt.Read[List[(String, String, String)]] =
    scopt.Read.reads { s =>
      val items = s.split(",")
      List((items.head, items(1), items(2)))
    }`

Comment: @Tanjin: And how should I use `paramsRead`?

Comment: It's an `implicit val`. You don't need to 'use' it in addition to your current code. Just paste it in the scope of your code and run your program/test. See what happens.

Comment: @Tanjin: Could you please post a link where I can read more about the implicit `scopt.Read` example that you posted?

Comment: https://github.com/scopt/scopt